# emacs change split bar style(or face)

Tags: emacs, split

I wonder how to change the window split bar style on emacs.
how to get it thicker, change its color or something
Please give me some hints to change it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to **window dividers**?:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Dividers.html

Comment: As to Emacs master branch, the `right-border-width` and `bottom-border-width` frame parameters work on Emacs for Windows, but not OSX.  I just filed a bug report:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22973  Here is an example of how to set it:  `(modify-frame-parameters (selected-frame) '((right-divider-width . 3) (bottom-divider-width . 3)))`  You can use the `default-frame-alist` if you want it to affect all frames.  There are several examples on the net that deal with setting the `default-frame-alist`.  Change colors with `M-x customize-face` -- see the link above for face names.